# Cannot create FactoryGirl's factory for model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot, database-cleaner

I have this situation with legacy project. Suppose I have rails model:

```
rails g model entity name:string
```

In that model there is `MAIN_ENTITY` constant:

```
class Entity < ActiveRecord::Base  
  MAIN_ENTITY_ID = 1
  MAIN_ENTITY = Entity.find(MAIN_ENTITY_ID)
end
```

Now I want to cover `Entity`-model with [rspec](http://rspec.info/) tests, but first I need factory. I created this factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :entity do
    name { FFaker::Company.name }
  end
end
```

And when I running `create(:entity)` inside [rspec](http://rspec.info/) test, I am getting this error:

```
Failure/Error: MAIN_ENTITY = Entity.find(MAIN_ENTITY_ID)

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound:
  Couldn't find Entity with 'id'=1
```

How to fix that without refactoring code and keeping `MAIN_ENTITY` constant?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Solution without refactoring (hack)

Ruby constants initializing before you access the static context of class. So, when you calling `Entity` class (manually or by using FactoryGirl), in background there is SQL query, which is trying to find record with `id == 1`.

In case of production, this code is working, but when you writing tests, your database usually is cleaning up after each test case run (rspec's `it`). So solution would be to create 'main entity' before each test case run in empty database:

```
# Your DatabaseCleaner initializer file
RSpec.configure do |config|
  # ...
  config.around(:each) do |example|
    DatabaseCleaner.cleaning do
      FactoryGirl.create_main_entity
      example.run
    end
  end
end
```

In `create_main_entity` method we have limitation here: we cannot use `Entity.create` or `Entity.new` methods, so we should use more low level solution: we need to make `INSERT` query directly into database. I would rewrite your `entities.rb`-factory like this:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :entity do
    name { FFaker::Company.name }
  end
end


module FactoryGirl
  def self.create_main_entity
    connection = ActiveRecord::Base.connection

    values = {
      id: 1,
      name: 'MAIN ENTITY',
      created_at: Time.now.to_s(:db),
      updated_at: Time.now.to_s(:db)
    }

    sql = <<-SQL
      INSERT INTO entities (#{values.keys.map {|k| k.to_s}.join(', ')})
      VALUES(#{values.values.map{"'%s'"}.join(', ')})
    SQL

    connection.insert(sql % values.values)
  end
end
```

#### Better solution with refactoring

My code above is temporary solution. I would recommend you to refactor your `Entity` model. Instead of initializing constant by finding record, you can use static method:

```
class Entity < ActiveRecord::Base
  MAIN_ENTITY_ID = 1

  def self.main_entity
    @@main_entity ||= Entity.find(MAIN_ENTITY_ID)
  end
end
```

I used memorization here `@@main_entity ||= ...` to avoid executing same SELECT-query on each `Entity.main_entity` call.

Comment: And would be nicer to not make code dependent on `id` of the `Entity`. Use some other unique attribute if possible e.g. `slug`, `title`, etc. whatever is globally unique.

Comment: Agree with you, @JagdeepSingh, there are situations, when `id` can be changed. For example we have two same-structured databases (two affiliates of the same company), and one day we will need to merge these two databases into one single database. So when `db2.Entity` will be merged into `db1.Entity`, `id`-s of `db1.Entity` will be changed. There are some other similar situations, like dumping part of database to json/xml, for importing this data somewhere else.